# IC's sensitivity

Tags: integrated-circuit, receiver, sensitivity

I'm trying to make an AM receiver using a certain IC (it's [Samsung KA22427C](https://lib.chipdip.ru/285/DOC000285545.pdf), if you ask). I found a datasheet and in AM section of electrical characteristics there is entry for maximum sensitivity that seems unusual.
It says that under test conditions:
Vcc = 12V
Vin = 37dBu
RL = 8Ohm
it's possible to obtain sensitivity of 1.5...3V. Which is odd to me. Is IC's sensitivity really that bad or did I just misunderstand test conditions? Because I don't get why do I need load resistance.
Does it mean that with input signal voltage of 37dBu I can obtain 1.5...3V of output signal on 8Ohm load?

Comment: Load resistance is the resistance of a speaker.

Comment: By Rl=8ohm on the datasheet, I'd assume that you should be sure not to use a speaker with a *lower than* 8ohm impedance (however, a 200ohm speaker should still work fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last statement would seem to be the correct interpretation:

An input of 37dBu (70uV) results in a typical output of 3v to the speaker. It is guaranteed to give at least 1.5v

I don't understand your second to last comment.

Comment: the datasheet wasn't written especially clearly & left room for confusion there. He wanted to be sure it wasn't soo incredibly insensitive that he had to feed it a 1.5V-3V AM signal.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB yes, that's what I meant.